# Printing types that change on different platforms

Tags: c, int, long-integer, format-specifiers

I need to store an array of items, where each item is 32 bits in length. So currently I'm using an array of `long`. However I'm compiling on another machine now where a `long` is 64 bits. This creates problems when it comes to signed numbers. (i.e. printing the same number on both machines, one will be negative (32-bit) and the other will be positive (64-bit).

So the plan is to switch to `int32_t`, the problem is that when using format strings to print the numbers out, the specifiers need to different as on the 32-bit machine `int32_t` is defined as a `long` and on the 64-bit machine it's defined as an `int`.

What is the best way to make sure that it will be 32-bits on whatever machine it's compiled on, and that the number can be printed? It seems like this is a lot of hassle and that there should be a simpler/easier way to have an array of items 32-bits in length.

Comment: Is saving in binary format an option for you? Then, you can use `fwrite` and `fread`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of doing it is to

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

and then use one of the format specifier macros:

```
void show(int32_t the_integer) {
  printf("The 32-value is %" PRId32 " in decimal.\n", the_integer);
}
```

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html

Comment: Oooh - about 10 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

There are macros defined in `<inttypes.h>` that help with exactly this problem. You use

```
"%" PRId32
```

as your print format specifier, and all will be well.

Comment: Note, without a space between the string and the macro, this won't work in a modern C++ compiler. Some C compilers might warn about the incompatibility.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - The question was tagged "C".

Comment: Hence I mentioned C. Even without that, many folks do run C code through C++ compilers.

Comment: I have made the edit. People really need to learn that these are different languages.